# <data:post.title> returns title of blog and not post title

Tags: post, blogger, blogspot

Hi I'm trying to convert a static html and css design to a blogger template. I've run into an issue where i expect the post includable to return the post title but instead is returning the blog title. Here is the includable code for the post and below it is the include code that is called in the main includable that houses the html structure. Please any ideas as to how i might resolve this would be very grateful.

```
<b:includable id='post' var='post'>
        <!--Article Summary-->
            <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
                <h1 class="article-title">
                    <data:post.title/>
                </h1>
            <b:else/>
                <h1 class="article-title">
                    <data:post.title/>
                </h1>
            </b:if>
            <p class="posted-by">
                by
                <em class="author-name"><data:post.author/></em>
                on
                <span class="date"><data:post.dateHeader/></span>
            </p>
            <p class="article-content">
                <data:post.body/>
            </p>
            <a href="" class="large-button orange-button-color button">READ MORE</a>
        </b:includable>
<b:if cond="data:blog.url ==  data:blog.homepageUrl">
  <div class="article-summary">
<img class="article-image" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/article-main-image.jpg" alt="article-main-image"/>
<b:include name="post"/>
</div>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

is correct, so instead I'd be curious about whether or not you're including from the right place. For example, are you in the MOBILE section vs the NON-MOBILE section of the template?